# i want to add pagination list of categories

Tags: categories, pagination

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $posts_per_page = 5;
    $offset = ($posts_per_page * $paged) - 12 ;

 $args = array(
 'orderby' => 'id',
 'hide_empty'=> 0,
'number' => $posts_per_page,
'offset' => $offset,
 'parent' => 0, //Child From Boxes Category 

);
$categories = get_categories($args);
 foreach ($categories as $cat) {
   echo '<li style="">';
 echo $cat->name;
     echo '<br />';


    echo '</li>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php    
    $args = array(
   'parent' => 0,
   'hide_empty' => 0
 );

$categories = get_categories( $args );
echo $cat =  ceil(count( $categories )/5);    
 ?>
 <?php
  $j=0;
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $posts_per_page = 5;
$offset = ($posts_per_page * $paged) - 5 ;
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent' => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 0,
'number' => $posts_per_page,
'offset' => $offset,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged

//'exclude'            => '1,3,24,9'
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
$j++;
 //echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' .       $category->name . '</a><br/>';
 $catname = $category->name;
 $catttid = $category->term_taxonomy_id;
  //}
   ?>

<div class="row"><h3 class="cat-title"><?php echo $catname; ?></h3><hr  class="space" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div></div>
   <!-- #main -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->
  <?php
  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo '<div class="paginate-links">';
  echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'prev_text' => __('<<'),
  'next_text' => __('>>'),
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $cat
     ) );
echo '</div>';
  ?>
```